# SQL WHERE clause only returning one of the results when there is 2 expected results

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Where clause in Stored Procedure that only returns one of 2 possible returns in a where clause

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[RPT_HC_ShiftRates]    Script Date: 01/23/2018 10:51:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure  [dbo].[RPT_HC_ShiftRates]

AS --variables
BEGIN
select c.Company
, c.OurReference
, Shifts1 as [Split shifts]
, Shifts2 as [Invoiced at one rate]
, s.PortalApproval
, s.Rates
, s.Breaks
, c.ClientID


from ClientSectorDefinedColumns s
join clients c on c.ClientID = s.ClientID
left OUTER JOIN ClientBranches AS CB ON C.ClientID = CB.BranchClientId

where (Shifts1 = 'y' or Shifts2 = 'y' or s.Rates is not null or s.Breaks is not null)
and (c.OurReference like 'P00%' or c.OurReference = 'HEA%')  
and C.ClientID in (select objectid from SectorObjects where SectorId in (58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 47 ))

END
```

The line I suspect is causing the issue is :

```
and (c.OurReference like 'P00%' or c.OurReference = 'HEA%')
```

This is only returning LIKE 'P00%' whereas it should be returning one or another.

I am new to SQL and only completed 20761B with little luck finding an answer in my training material.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: `c.OurReference = 'HEA%'` - considering the context, shouldn't that `=` be a `LIKE`? Would that help?

Comment: Absolutely the one. Thank you very much @RuudHelderman pop it as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you had the intention of doing a pattern match.
In the first part of the condition you did it the right way:

```
c.OurReference like 'P00%'
```

but in the second part, you accidentally used `=` instead of `LIKE`:

```
c.OurReference = 'HEA%'
```

A mistake like this is easily overlooked.
The right-hand side of the condition does contain a percent sign (`%`),
but in the absence of `LIKE`, it is not interpreted by SQL Server as a wildcard.
Instead, the character is matched 'as-is'.
The condition will only succeed if column `OurReference` is *literally* `HEA%`.
In your database, that is never the case; no records will match that part of the condition.